# How to combine two xml elements into one JAXB Class generated using xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am using some xsd like this. This will generate a class with two fields name1 and name2.
What I want is to generate a class with one field completeName with by combining both fields.

```
<xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may move your @XmlValue or @XmlAttribute Annoation to the setter methods and customize your setters there. In your case it probably makes more sense, however, to store the two values atomic in two separate fields and have a custom "getCombinedName" method in your jaxb class like this.

```
public String getCombinedName() {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```